# Train DL model using tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to do a simple Deep Learning task to learn how to use Tensorflow (and especially its Dataset tool). The task is the following : training a model which can tell if the sum of a given sequence of floats (length is fixed) is positive (labelled as 1) or negative (labelled as 0).

I did the following without using tf.data.Dataset and it works well.

```py
def get_rand_seq():
    return [rand.uniform(-1, 1) for _ in range(6)]

n = 1000
X = np.array([get_rand_seq() for _ in range(n)])
y = np.array([0 if sum(seq) < 0 else 1 for seq in X])

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, input_shape=(6, ), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, batch_size=4)
```

Still, when I'm trying to do the same using a tf.data.Dataset input, I'm getting an error at the training step `model.fit(...)`
Here is my code :

```py
ds_X = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(X)
ds_y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds_X, ds_y))

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, input_shape=(6, ), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

model.fit(ds, epochs=10, batch_size=4)
```

I get the following error :

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_5 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 6 but received input with shape [6, 1]
```

Even changing the input_shape to (6, 1) doesn't make it worked.

Is there a kind soul to enlighten a lost sheep like me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `batch_size` argument in `model.fit` when using `tf.data.Dataset`. You should act on the dataset itself (remember that any operation on dataset like batching, shuffeling etc... **does not change the dataset in place** which means a copy of dataset with new properties is returned and dataset should be overwritten)

Also, there is no need to create two distinct datasets and zip them. You can provide a tuple to the factory method to `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np

def get_rand_seq():
    return [np.random.uniform(-1, 1) for _ in range(6)]

n = 1000
X = np.array([get_rand_seq() for _ in range(n)])
y = np.array([0 if sum(seq) < 0 else 1 for seq in X])
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y)).batch(4)

# equivalent is 
# ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y))
# ds = ds.batch(4) # not in-place

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, input_shape=(6, ), activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

model.fit(ds, epochs=1000)
```